# Dealing with loop, fluidRow and column in shiny

Tags: r, shiny

I'm trying to make a Shiny application that display multiple plots on different rows and allow user to select the proper tendencies by using the radioButtons situated beside the graph.  The problem is that I'm not able to get the radioButtons located directly beside the plots.

I want:

[image]

And I get: 
[image]

My code:

server.R:

```
library(shiny)

shinyServer(function(input, output) {

  lapply(1:3, function(iter) {
    output[[paste0("g",iter)]] <- renderPlot({

    set.seed(iter)
    xx <- rnorm(10)
    yy <- rnorm(10)
    plot(xx,yy)
    abline(reg=lm(yy~xx), col=2, lwd=ifelse(input[[paste0("radio",iter)]]==1,2,1))
    abline(reg=lm(yy~xx+0), col=3, lwd=ifelse(input[[paste0("radio",iter)]]==2,2,1))

  })
  })

})
```

ui.R:

```
library(shiny)

shinyUI(fluidPage(

  titlePanel("My loop test"),

  fluidRow(
    column(6,
    lapply(1:3, function(iter) { 
      plotOutput(paste0("g",iter))
    }  
    )), 
    column(3,
      lapply(1:3, function(iter){
      radioButtons(paste0("radio",iter),label = "buttons", choices = list("with intercept"=1,"without intersept"=2),selected = 1)      

    }
    ))

  )
))
```

I hope it's clear.  I'm new to Shiny (but not R) and I'm still in the steep part of the learning curve!

Thanks

Comment: Plots have a default height of 400px, so you can put radioButtons inside divs or another container with the same height.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Maybe something like this:

```
shinyUI(fluidPage(
  titlePanel("My loop test"),
  lapply(1:3, function(iter) {
    fluidRow(
      column(
        6, 
        plotOutput( paste0("g",iter) )
      ),
      column(
        3,
        radioButtons(
          paste0("radio", iter), 
          label = "buttons",
          choices = list("with intercept"=1,"without intersept"=2),
          selected = 1)
        )
      )
  })
))
```

Comment: Works but you have a parenthesis problem (the one at the third row from the buttom has to be remove).  thanks

Answer (score 3):

This is a good use case for modules. I didn't get the buttons to line up perfectly, but that could be fixed with some CSS:

```
library(shiny)

myModUI <- function(id) {
  ns <- NS(id)

  tagList(
  fluidRow(
    splitLayout(cellWidths=c("75%","25%"),
      plotOutput(ns("g")),
      radioButtons(ns("radio"),label = "buttons",
                   choices = list("with intercept"=1,"without intersept"=2),
                   selected = 1))      
    )
  )

} 

myMod <- function(input, output, server, seed) {

  output$g <- renderPlot({
    set.seed(seed)
    xx <- rnorm(10)
    yy <- rnorm(10)
    plot(xx,yy)
    abline(reg=lm(yy~xx), col=2, lwd=ifelse(input$radio==1,2,1))
    abline(reg=lm(yy~xx+0), col=3, lwd=ifelse(input$radio==2,2,1))

  })

  return(reactive(input$radio))

}

server <- shinyServer(function(input, output, server) {

  lapply(1:5,function(i) {
    callModule(myMod,i,seed=i)
  })

})

ui <- shinyUI(fluidPage(

  titlePanel("My loop test"),
  mainPanel(
  lapply(1:5,function(i) {
    myModUI(i)
  })
  )
))

shinyApp(ui=ui,server=server)
```

Note that `fluidRow` isn't enough, we have to use `splitLayout`